# Expected number of distinct elements in a sample

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a random sampling with replacement from a population with $N$ distinct elements, let $X$ be the number of distinct elements included in the sample.If $n$ be the sample size, find $E(X)$ and $V(X)$

***What I attempted***
I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not.
 I think minimum value $X$ can take is $1$, that is, all the elements of the sample is same. Since there are $N$ elements in the population the required probability is $\frac{N}{N^n}$
Similarly, $P(X=2)=\frac{N(N-1)}{N^n}$
$P(X=3)=\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{N^n}$

(Proceeding in this  way), I have

$P(X=n)=\frac{N(N-1)(N-2).............(N-n+1)}{N^n}$
Therefore, $E(X)=1.\frac{N}{N^n}+2.\frac{N(N-1)}{N^n}+...........+n.\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{N^n}=\frac{1}{N^n}(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k. ^NP_k)$

However, after the examination, some of my classmates pointed out that they got something different. Their answer was $E(X)=N[1-(\frac{N-1}{N})^n]$
One of them asked me why I did not use the recurrence relation. I was not able to understand what he was meaning.

Is my approach correct? Have I made any mistake?

Comment: As for your answer, you will find that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{N(N-1)\cdots(N-k+1)}{N^n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^n} < \frac{N!e}{N^n}, $$ which is usually much smaller than $1$. So you are definitely missing something. As it turns out, you forgot to take 'arrangements of numbers' into consideration.

Comment: Thank you Sangchul Lee. However, I have not understood yet what you are meaning by "arrangements of numbers". Would it be possible for you to elaborate it more ?

Comment: Consider an easy case $N = 2$ and $n = 3$. It is true that there are $N = 2$ cases for $X = 1$, namely $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$. But for $X = 2$, we already have 6 cases $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(1,2,2)$, $(2,1,2)$, $(2,2,1)$. Here we see that simply picking out $x$ different numbers is not enough for computing $\mathsf{P}[X = x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When counting random things, it is often powerful to adopt the method of indicator functions.

Let $Y_i$ be the $i$-th sample, and let $X_n$ be the number of distinct samples up to the $n$-th sampling. If we denote the indicator function of the event $A$ by $\mathbf{1}[A]$, then

\begin{align*}
X_n
&= X_{n-1} + \mathbf{1}[Y_n \notin \{Y_1, \cdots, Y_{n-1}\}] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}[Y_i \notin \{ Y_1, \cdots, Y_{i-1} \}].
\end{align*}

Now given the size $X_{n-1}$ of the set $\{Y_1, \cdots, Y_{n-1}\}$, we compute the following probability

$$ \mathsf{P}[Y_n \notin \{Y_1, \cdots, Y_{n-1}\} \mid X_{n-1}] = 1 - \frac{X_{n-1}}{N}. $$

So it follows that $\mathsf{E}[X_1] = 1$ and

$$ \mathsf{E}[X_n]
= \mathsf{E}[X_{n-1}] + \mathsf{E}\left[ 1 - \frac{X_{n-1}}{N} \right]
= 1 + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right) \mathsf{E}[X_{n-1}].$$

Solving this recurrence relation yields

$$ \mathsf{E}[X_n]
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right)^k
= N \left( 1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{N}\right)^n \right) $$

as claimed by the classmates. $\mathsf{E}[X_n^2]$ can be computed in a similar way, from which you can compute the variance as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another (easier?) way to use indicator variables:

Let $Z_i = 1$ if the $i$th sample has NOT appeared before, or $0$ if it has.  So $E[Z_i] =$ probability all previous samples were different $= (\frac{N-1}{N})^{i-1}$.

Now $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ so by linearity of expectations $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{N-1}{N})^{i-1} = N ( 1 - (\frac{N-1}{N})^{n})$ as desired.

Comment: Ah, this sounds much neater. (+1)

Comment: @SangchulLee - I thought you were using my approach when I read the first few lines of your posted solution.  But suddenly you turned it into a recurrence, which I totally did not see coming.  That was a neat surprise for me too.

Comment: The difference is that my solution tracks the set of samples in $n$, while your solution focuses on each individual and see if it is sampled or not. And when I saw your solution, I immediately knew that your one is much neater and more elegant to work with. :)